# Add syslog handler in Laravel for paperTrail .

Tags: php, laravel, logging, rsyslog, papertrail-app

How could i link Laravel log files to PaperTrial ?

According to this article :

http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-forge-logging-with-papertrail#step-4-add-a-syslog-handler

I followed steps and reached to step 4 putting Syslog Monolog handler in the /app/route.php file ,went to PaperTrial dashboard  but i didn't  see any output.

Any help ? thanks.

Comment: Did you throw an exception? From the docs: "Try throwing an exception in your code to see your Laravel logs show up in your Papertrail account."

Comment: Yes i did, but nothing appear on the dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 5.1 after setting up the forge, you should add  to **bootstrap/app.php** file the following code **just before** the return of the **$app** variable

```
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog){
        $monolog->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\SyslogHandler('papertrail'));
    });

return $app;
```

The parameter (in this case 'papertrail') can be whatever you want to, this name will show on the papertail's event screen.

Comment: This seems to stop Laravel logging to the normal 'laravel.log' file. Is there a way to have it logging to both paper trail and the existing local log file?

Answer (score 1):

I have it working using the standard logging facility instead of Monolog. This way there is nothing extra to install. Just **add this to rsyslogd's conf**:

```
### Laravel Log
$InputFileName /path/to/vhost/dir/app/storage/logs/laravel.log
$InputFileTag laravel-errors-domain.com:
$InputFileStateFile state-laravel-errors-domain.com
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

And make sure that this log gets included in the send action, if you are not sending everything.

Then issue

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using Laravel 5.2.* with Forge, Step 4 from that article is not necessary anymore. All you have to do after Step 3 is set your Environment `.env` settings in Forge to `APP_LOG=syslog` for each site you want to use with papertrail.

However, this means that Laravel will not log to `laravel.log` anymore in this environment. But, in other environments (e.g. dev environment) you could of course continue logging to `laravel.log` by simply not making any changes to the `.env` file there.

Comment: Update: Newer versions of Laravel use LOG_CHANNEL instead of APP_LOG. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#configuration